# How to use Random Undersampler with ratio = 'dict' in imblearn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error, imblearn

I am trying to deal with imbalanced data set using imblearn's [random under-sampler](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html#imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler). I want to specify the number of labels to be under-sampled manually. Here is my code:

```
sm = RandomUnderSampler(ratio = {0:142498, 1: 495}, random_state=42)
X_train, y_train = sm.fit_sample(X_tr,encoded_Ytrain)
print(format(Counter(y_train)))
```

However, this throws the error:

> File "first_approach.py", line 56, in < module >
>       X_train, y_train = sm.fit_sample(X_tr,encoded_Ytrain)
>       raise ValueError('Unknown parameter type for ratio.') ValueError: Unknown parameter type for ratio.

What should be the correct syntax for passing the same?

Answer (score 1):

depending on the version you're using, instead of "ratio" you have to use "sampling_strategy" when you're using a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing version 0.3

imblearn 0.2.1 does not support the dictionary. You will need to install it from the source.

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn.git
```